# How do I force a program to appear to run out of memory?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, memory-management

I have a C/C++ program that might be hanging when it runs out of memory.  We discovered this by running many copies at the same time.  I want to debug the program without completely destroying performance on the development machine.  Is there a way to limit the memory available so that a new or malloc will return a NULL pointer after, say, 500K of memory has been requested?

Comment: Linux, specifically CentOS 32 bit running kernel 2.6.18-128.1.16.el5

Comment: Hmm. When I first read the title..I was thinking... char *foo = new char[(1024 * 1024) * 10]; perhaps, lol.. Just a weird quirk I'd probably try, lol

Comment: Then I read Tom's answer below and it kinda makes sense to me.

Comment: This thread has some additional good ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109000/how-to-simulate-memory-allocation-errors

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try turning the question on its head and asking how to limit the amount of memory an OS will allow your process to use.

Try looking into http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html

Try say:
    ulimit -v

Here is another link that's a little old but gives a little more back ground:
http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_77.html

Comment: This worked for me.  Thanks!  Specifically, I ran the program, used `ps` to get the process ID, then `cat /proc/PID/status` to get VmPeak and VmSize in kB (817756 in my case).  I then ran `ulimit -v 800000` and tried again, and quickly got into an out-of-memory situation (0 returned from a malloc).  I could also run it under gdb (`gdb --args ./program --arg1 --arg2`) and trace the code.

Answer (score 9):

One way is to write a wrapper around malloc().

```
static unsigned int requested =0;

void* my_malloc(size_tamount){

   if (requested + amount < LIMIT){
       requested+=amount;
       return malloc(amount);
   }

   return NULL
}
```

Your could use a #define to overload your malloc.

As GMan states, you could overload new / delete operators as well (for the C++ case).

Not sure if that's the best way, or what you are looking for

Comment: Better would be to over load global operator new/delete, because all allocations will have to go through that, without changing any other code.

Comment: Yes, overloading new / delete will help. Consider this a malloc overload. Editing my answer

Comment: And you might consider making LIMIT settable at run-time, eg via an environment variable.

Answer (score 5):

- Which OS?  For Unix, see ulimit -d/limit datasize depending on your shell (sh/csh).
- You can write a wrapper for malloc which returns an error in the circonstance you want.  Depending on your OS, you may be able to substitute it for the implementation's one.

Answer (score 4):

An other way of doing it is to use [failmalloc](http://www.nongnu.org/failmalloc/) which is a shared library that overrides malloc etc. and then fail :-). It gives you control over when to fail and can be made to fail randomly, every nth time etc.

I havent used it my self but have heard good things.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on your platform.  For example, this can be achieved programmatically on Unix-like platforms using **[setrlimit(RLIMIT_DATA, ...)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/getrlimit.html)**.

**EDIT**:

The RLIMIT_AS resource may also be useful in this case as well.

Comment: Against GNU libc, RLIMIT_DATA is powerless.

Answer (score 3):

Override new and new[].

```
void* operator new(size_t s)
{
}
void* operator new[](size_t s)
{
}
```

Put your own code in the braces to selectively die after X number of calls to new.  Normally you would call malloc to allocate the memory and return it.

Answer (score 2):

I once had a student in CS 1 (in C, yeah, yeah, not my fault) try this, and ran out of memory:

```
int array[42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42][42]..... (42 dimensions);
```

and then he wanted to know why it gave errors...

Comment: No wonder... He was trying to create an array of size `1.5013093754529657235677197216425e+68`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to spend money, there's a tool called Holodeck by SecurityInnovations, which lets you inject faults into your program (including low memory).  Nice thing is you can turn stuff on and off at will.  I haven't really used it, much, so I don't know if it's possible to program in faults at certain points with the tool.  I also don't know what platforms are supported...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, on Linux, [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) will never return a null pointer. Instead, the [OOM Killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) will get called. This is, of course, unless you've disabled the OOM Killer. Some googling should come up with a result.

I know this isn't your actual question, but it does have to do with where you're coming from.

Comment: Sometimes the OOM gets called, sometimes you get a NULL pointer: http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2006/11/30/linux-out-of-memory.html?page=1

Comment: The article "When Linux Runs Out of Memory" by Mulyadi Santos, published 2006, is no longer available. Here's the wayback machine link: https://web.archive.org/web/20160907133439/http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2006/11/30/linux-out-of-memory.html?page=1