# What is a good way to force Perl 5 to run out of memory quickly on OS X?

Tags: perl, macos, memory

I am trying to test a specific condition the will only occur if `perl` has a `malloc` that fails due to there being no memory left.  I would like `perl` to die as quickly as possible.  I figured the fasted way would be create some huge arrays like

`perl -le '$_->[100_000_000_000] = 1 for \(@a, @b, @c, @d); <>'`

But I had to kill it after my swap hit 5 gig with no signs of stopping (I am on OS X 10.6).

I just tested it on Linux and it dies pretty quick:

```
time perl -le '$_->[1_000_000_000] = 1 for \(@a, @b, @c, @d); <>'
Out of memory!

real    0m0.023s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.008s
```

So the problem seems to be OS X and its `dynamic_pager`.

I just tried disabling the `dynamic_pager` with

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.dynamic_pager.plist
```

and rebooting, but the machine just hangs completely.  My next attempt will be to change the `com.apple.dynamic_pager.plist` config file to write the vm files to a very small partition.

Comment: Strange that you didn't `"x" x 9e9`.

Comment: @tsee It takes time to build the string, but `perl -e '@a[9e8]=1'` is effectively just a `malloc`.

Comment: "I had to kill it after my swap hit 5 gig with no signs of stopping (I am on OS X 10.6)." - Mac OS X shows that type of behavior often, including the cases like `malloc(-1)`. Try any other OS where you can explicitly disable swap. (Never tried doing that on my Mac - but do that casually on the Linux.)

Comment: @Dummy00001 I tired in on Linux already, it ran out of memory instantly.

Answer (score 5):

In a previous question "[How to simulate memory allocation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109000/how-to-simulate-memory-allocation-errors)", user [freespace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8297/freespace) suggested using `ulimit` with a test user account to limit the amount of memory that could be used.  This may do what you want without having to allocate huge amounts of memory.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work on OS X.  I tried `ulimit -m 64; perl -e '$s = "x" x (1024*1024*100); <>'` and checked memory usage and the perl program owned two hundred megabytes.

Comment: IIRC it should be `ulimit -d`, not `-m`.